# How to filter array of hashes by two pairs of `key => value` in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of hashes:

```
array = [
{:created_at => 1520913341, :event_id => '111', :album_id => '123'},
{:created_at => 1520740541, :event_id => '234', :album_id => '999'},
{:created_at => 1520654141, :event_id => '111', :album_id => '777'},
{:created_at => 1520394941, :event_id => '233', :album_id => '444'},
{:created_at => 1520049341, :event_id => '890', :album_id => '765'}
 ]
```

i need to keep hashes with all `:event_id` and if `:event_id` is duplicated keep the one with earliest `:created_at`.How can i do that in ruby?

i expect to get in the response following:

```
[
{:created_at => 1520740541, :event_id => '234', :album_id => '999'},
{:created_at => 1520654141, :event_id => '111', :album_id => '777'},
{:created_at => 1520394941, :event_id => '233', :album_id => '444'},
{:created_at => 1520049341, :event_id => '890', :album_id => '765'}
 ]
```

Comment: updated my question. Thanks @CarySwoveland!

Comment: Thanks for clarification, i updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

```
array.sort_by { |h| h[:created_at] }.uniq { |h| h[:event_id] }
  #=> [{:created_at=>1520049341, :event_id=>"890", :album_id=>"765"},
  #    {:created_at=>1520394941, :event_id=>"233", :album_id=>"444"},
  #    {:created_at=>1520654141, :event_id=>"111", :album_id=>"777"},
  #    {:created_at=>1520740541, :event_id=>"234", :album_id=>"999"}]
```

See [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), in particular, "`self` is traversed in order, and the first occurrence is kept.".

Comment: After posting I saw that my answer was given earlier by @ManojMonga in a comment posted on Subash's answer.

Comment: @ManojMonga, if you wish to post your answer I will happily delete mine.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
array.group_by { |t| t[:event_id] }.map { |_,hash| hash.min_by { |t| t[:created_at]} }.sort_by {|t| -t[:created_at]}
```

Comment: it returns me only one hash `{:created_at=>1520049341, :event_id=>"890", :album_id=>"765"}` but i need all `event_ids` except  duplicated  based on earliest `:created_at`

Comment: You mean you only need the `event_ids` or the whole hash?

Comment: i expect to get only this [
{:created_at => 1520740541, :event_id => '234', :album_id => '999'},
{:created_at => 1520654141, :event_id => '111', :album_id => '777'},
{:created_at => 1520394941, :event_id => '233', :album_id => '444'},
{:created_at => 1520049341, :event_id => '890', :album_id => '765'}
 ]

Comment: the first hash form the  array needs to be filtered out because 1. it's duplicated event_id 2. :created_at is later than for the third hash

Comment: You should sort the array first and then call uniq on it. `array.sort_by {|t| t[:created_at]}.uniq {|t| [t[:event_id]]}` so that it keeps the the correct one.

Comment: Thank you, guys! I appreciate this!

Comment: Rather than editing your answer with a near-identical answer to mine, the sporting thing to do would have been to point out the final array in my answer wasn't sorted.

Comment: @SagarPandya Yes, you are right, my last edit was somewhat based from your answer, I was testing mine on the console and just wanted it to produce the exact result, sorry if you feel ripped off.

Comment: Okay, no worries. In future you may wish to credit or acknowledge another user if you have based your answer on theirs. I've upvoted your answer and deleted mine now.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thank you for upvoting my answer, that was really nice of you.